# Reading strings, integers and doubles from file with GoLang

Tags: file, variables, go

How to read data from file in Google Go when my data file looks like this:

```
SomeString      200.0   2
OtherString     100.6   9
OneMoreString   550.8   1
```

(String, double and integer). I tried `bufio.readLine` and `bufio.readString` but these are reading whole line, while i need seperated variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this might work--if you've got spaces in your string, you might need to handle that differently:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os"
)

func main() {
   f, err := os.Open("scan.txt")
   if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
   }
   for {
      var i int
      var flt float64
      var str string
      var n int
      n, err = fmt.Fscanln(f, &str, &flt, &i)
      if n == 0 || err != nil {
        break
      }
      fmt.Println("string:", str, "; float:", flt, "; int:", i)
   }
}
```

outputs:

```
string: SomeString ; float: 200 ; int: 2
string: OtherString ; float: 100.6 ; int: 9
string: OneMoreString ; float: 550.8 ; int: 1
```